# jQuery Waypoints throws Uncaught Error: No handler option passed to Waypoint constructor

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am using waypoint version 3.1.1 with the jquery version also using the sticky shortcut with this as my call code

```
$('.navWrap').waypoint('sticky', {
  direction: 'up',
});
```

But I get an "Uncaught Error: No handler option passed to Waypoint constructor" and the waypoint does not fire.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, from what the error states, did you have an handler option passed to the constructor?

Comment: Thanks for the laugh, If I knew how to pass the handler to the constructor I would :)

Comment: Right in the example in the docs: https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, waypoints requires a "handler" option, which defines a callback function when you scroll to your waypoint element:

```
$('.navWrap').waypoint('sticky', {
    direction: 'up',
    handler: function(direction) {
        alert(direction);
    }
});
```

You could also try doing this using the new no-framework paradigm:

```
var sticky = new Waypoint.Sticky({
  element: $('.navWrap')[0]
});
```

See docs here:

https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints

Comment: the no-framework option worked flawlessly. I have more to learn about waypoint. Thanks, @Steven Moseley!

Comment: As of Waypoints 3.0 the sticky shortcut isn't something that can be created via `$(thing).waypoint('sticky')`. It must be created the way Steven mentioned using `new Waypoint.Sticky`.